# Need guidance on data modelling dynamodb for below example

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I have flowchart like below (logical design) sorry for my bad shaped diagram (just created in paint) my apologies for that. But now I need guidance how to put this representation in dynamo db table definition. I am newbie to dynamo db and reading through different types of data types which i use, I could still think of map type for some of the attributes, but still dont have full view how can i efficiently.

What I need is: to put these logical design into single dynamodb table . I need table definition (i.e which data type is suitable for which attribute)

Note: Yes or No which is there in green font in diagram are actual values all others are hierarchy labels

Note1: In diagram, that parent can be treated as customer_id

[image]

Comment: I would like to know your access pattern. For example, how are these data queried? By id? by type?

Comment: @jellycsc  actually yes or No which are in green are acutal values to be retrieved. and regarding accessing pattern  for example category by VM , another example by Type i.e AZ or GC  and again i can also do Type-->AZ-->OCA -->Deck -- what is status for this combo like this. you can assume that Parent is Customer_ID

Comment: You mentioned previously in the chat, the maximum # of items your table has would be only 500. Then you can simply store it in json and do a scan every time you want to retrieve something. Not a big deal.

Comment: yeah, but actually there UI applicatio which feeds data (which is yes or no)into this table ..so it was necessary to create table and let the UI feed the data so trying to figure out which is best table definition for this

Comment: so ideally, queried by customer_id which parent in above diagram